# Redundant superclass constraint warning for generic class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have viewController class that implements a generic type Model class and a generic TableCell that needs to inherit from a generic baseClass using the same Model type as the viewController.
Doing it like below throws the warning `Redundant superclass constraint 'M' : 'Object'`. I don't quite see how I could do it without the warning, since `BaseTableView` is itself dependent on `M`.

```
public class BaseTableView<M:Object, C:BaseTableCell<M>>: UIViewController {

  typealias Model = M
  typealias TableCell = C

  (...)
}
```

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to that question. Apparently it has no bad runtime effects though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is because the definition of BaseTableCell is already enforcing conformance to Object. You can change your class definition to:

```
public class BaseTableView<M, C:BaseTableCell<M>>: UIViewController {
    (...)
}
```

This should resolve your warning and retain expected functionality.

Comment: That ... actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks for pointing that out! :)